# how do i link wininet library with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

This is c++ code to get IP address (main.cpp) (project -> Prueba2 ).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>

std::string real_ip() {

    HINTERNET net = InternetOpen("IP retriever",
                                 INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,
                                 NULL,
                                 NULL,
                                 0);

    HINTERNET conn = InternetOpenUrl(net,
                                     "http://myexternalip.com/raw",
                                     NULL,
                                     0,
                                     INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD,
                                     0);

    char buffer[4096];
    DWORD read;

    InternetReadFile(conn, buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]), &read);
    InternetCloseHandle(net);

    return std::string(buffer, read);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << real_ip() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt file for compiling.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(Prueba2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(Prueba2 main.cpp)
```

I have to link this library but i don't know how, this error appears. I know how to compile it with g++ adding the library with -lwininet and it works correctly, i'm trying to do it with cmake now. Thank you for your help

```
undefined reference to `__imp_InternetOpenA'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2022.1.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/JAVIER/CLionProjects/Prueba2/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `__imp_InternetOpenUrlA'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2022.1.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/JAVIER/CLionProjects/Prueba2/main.cpp:23: undefined reference to `__imp_InternetReadFile'
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2022.1.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/JAVIER/CLionProjects/Prueba2/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `__imp_InternetCloseHandle'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html):

```
...
add_executable(Prueba2 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Prueba2 wininet)
```

Comment: it did work, i was writing cpp file in target parameter. Thx u!

Comment: @javiarago1 Glad to hear it! You're welcome!